# trace svg path (get x,y coordinates at discrete steps)

Tags: javascript, svg

How can I find a number of (evenly spaced) points on an SVG path?

I found it being done here on this [code pen](https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/epXvKg?editors=1010):

```
var bezierData = MorphSVGPlugin.pathDataToBezier("#anim_path");
```

However, it depends on some proprietary code, the [MorphSVGPlugin](https://greensock.com/morphSVG).

[image]

Is there any non-proprietary code around for this functionality (path in, coordinates out)?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/getPointAtLength

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I would do it:
I need to know the length of the path (`thePath.getTotalLength()`) and the number of segments: 10 in this case. Then I calculate the position of the points on the path using the method `getPointAtLength` Finally I draw a circle for every point on the path.

```js
var SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
let pathLength = thePath.getTotalLength();
let nSegments = 10;
// the segment length:
let segment = pathLength/nSegments;
for( let i = 0; i<=nSegments; i++){
 let p = thePath.getPointAtLength(i*segment);
 let o = {r:2, cx:p.x,cy:p.y} 
  drawCircle(o, svg)
}



function drawCircle(o, parent) {
  var circle = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'circle');
  for (var name in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      circle.setAttributeNS(null, name, o[name]);
    }
  }
  parent.appendChild(circle);
  return circle;
}
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid;}
#thePath{fill:none; stroke:black;}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="-10 20 120 60">
  <path id="thePath" d="M0,75Q33,75 50,50 T100,25"/>
</svg>
```