# Move a SVG icon along a Path in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, svg, xamarin.forms

Is there a best practice on how to animate and move a SVG icon along a path of (x/y) coordinates in Xamarin.Forms?

With [Xamarin.Forms.Shapes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/shapes/) there is the [Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/shapes/path) class. I could draw some path in an Editor like [Figma](https://www.figma.com/), copy-paste the path in a [Xaml Path instance](https://youtu.be/Q75npY6MToo) like David Ortinau shows it.

But how to move a SVG icon from the begin to the end of such path?

[image]

Comment: I think you could move an object like a BoxView using Translate(x,y).Hope this can help you!

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT That is not the question. To move any object for ONE (x,y) coordinate TranslateTo(x,y) could be used. I seek for a way to 1.) get the SVG Path coordinates (x/y) array and 2.) a TranslateTo(xyArray) way.

Comment: You need to know the length of the path and then draw a circle for every point on the path.Please refer to this thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54690809/trace-svg-path-get-x-y-coordinates-at-discrete-steps

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT Thanks, but has nothing to do with Xamarin.Forms. Anyway I'm working on a solution and if it works I'll post it as the answer

Comment: What came to my mind first is that we can  use `SkiaSharp` to implement the function of moving along a variable path of x/y coordinates.Please refer to this example,https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/main/SkiaSharpForms/Demos/Demos/SkiaSharpFormsDemos/Transforms/HendecagramAnimationPage.cs

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT Thanks for your last comment. But thats still not the answer to that topic. I selfanswered in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I found out until now, there is not best practice for this topic.
With Xamarin.Forms Shapes and Path it can be done by traversing the 
[Path.Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.shapes.path.data#xamarin-forms-shapes-path-data) which is a Geometry instance and extract the (x,y) coords point by point. Afterwards all the extracted points can be used to call [TranslateTo(x,y)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.viewextensions.translateto) point by point on e.g. a BoxView to move along a path.

With SkiaSharp this sample sounds reasonable.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/curves/information#traversing-the-path